# Operação com matriz

Tags: javascript

Tenho uma lista de produtos e um lista de preços destes produtos por mercado, de maneira que cada mercado tem sua `basket` (cesta de produtos com preço).

Ocorre que preciso de um função que retorne o menor preço total da lista para dois mercados combinados entre si.

> Exemplo: uma lista com 5 produtos distintos e pelo menos 4 mercados
>   possuem estes produtos disponíveis para venda. Como fazer para, a cada
>   dois mercados analisados, calcular o custo total da lista, sempre
>   pegando o menor preço entre os dois mercados.

**EXEMPLO**:

```
listCompra = [ product1, product2, product3, product4, product5 ]
```

Qual o menor preço total considerando a combinação entre dois mercados ?

```
//baskets matrix (Produto, Preço)
supermarket1 = basket1 [     [product1, 10,0]
                            ,[product2, 12,0]
                            ,[product3, 11,0]
                            ,[product4, 9,0]
                            ,[product5, 8,0]  ];

supermarket2 = basket2 [     [product1, 13,0]
                            ,[product2, 11,0]
                            ,[product3, 10,0]
                            ,[product4, 10,0]
                            ,[product5, 9,0]  ];

supermarket3 = basket3 [     [product1, 11,0]
                            ,[product2, 9,0]
                            ,[product3, 12,0]
                            ,[product4, 9,0]
                            ,[product5, 7,0] ];

supermarket4 = basket4 [     [product1, 8,0]
                            ,[product2, 11,0]
                            ,[product3, 9,0]
                            ,[product4, 7,0]
                            ,[product5, 16,0] ];
```

Comment: Jose, em relação ao problema que foi apresentado, poderia especificar qual a sua dúvida?

Comment: Não entendi a estrutura dessa matrix.

Comment: a estrutura é basket = [ [produto, valor] ], porem na edição o valor saiu com ',' como separador decimal mas deveria ser '.' (ponto). Considere o valor com ponto.

Answer (score 0):

Cada basket possui uma lista de compras, composta em Produto e Valor. Cada basket representa o valor da lista em um mercado. Imagina que vc tenha que comprar 5 produtos e já pesquisou o preço nos 4 supermercados distintos, se vc puder ir a dois supermercados qual seria os dois a serem escolhidos ? Sendo o critério o menor preço total da lista.